# How to change AWS SWF domain retention period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

Is it possible to change the retention period of a SWF domain? If it is, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWF doesn't provide a way to do that. The only thing you can do is deprecate the existing domain, create a new one with the required retention period and start using the latter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!